# Expires-date in auto renewable subscription less than current date

Tags: ios, subscription, mkstorekit

In MKStoreKit I buy auto renewable subscription. If you buy for a year then the method checks whether the subscription is valid isSubscriptionActive returns 1. But if we assume a month, expires-date once it is less than the current date. What could be the problem?

```
2014-06-22 16:11:45.160 ForTraderApp[3035:60b] expiresDate = 1402747114000.000000
2014-06-22 16:11:45.161 ForTraderApp[3035:60b] currentDate = 1403439105.161849
```

MKStoreKit v.5
ios7.1

```
- (BOOL) isSubscriptionActive:(NSString*) featureId
{
   MKSKSubscriptionProduct *subscriptionProduct = [self.subscriptionProducts   objectForKey:featureId];
   if(!subscriptionProduct.receipt) return NO;

   id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:subscriptionProduct.receipt options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
   NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:[jsonObject objectForKey:@"latest_receipt"]];

   NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
   NSDictionary *payloadDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:receiptData
                                                                    options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                     format:&plistFormat
                                                                      error:nil];

    receiptData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:[payloadDict objectForKey:@"purchase-info"]];

    NSDictionary *receiptDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:receiptData
                                                                    options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                     format:&plistFormat
                                                                      error:nil];

    NSTimeInterval expiresDate = [[receiptDict objectForKey:@"expires-date"] doubleValue]/1000.0f;

    NSLog(@"expiresDate = %f", [[receiptDict objectForKey:@"expires-date"] doubleValue]);
    NSLog(@"date = %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);

    return expiresDate > [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
}
```

Comment: First, I don't understand your question completely. But if you have a method to compare two dates and the result is incorrect, you need to include that method in the question.

Comment: I edit question. The problem is that immediately after the subscription date of completion of the subscription is less than the current date, although there must be at least 10 minutes in sandbox mode.